# Page go to top when i click on next/prev button in gliderjs

Tags: javascript, html

i'm using glider Js plugin and whenever i click on next/prev button the page goes to top ,in jquery i added e.preventDefault and it worked but in this case i don't know what to do .. 
here is the code:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    new Glider(document.querySelector('.glider-profil-service'),{


     slidesToShow: 3.5,
     slidesToScroll: 1,
     draggable: true,
     dots: '.dots',
     arrows: {
       prev: '.glider-prev',
       next: '.glider-next'
     }
   });
    });
```

any help would be great

Comment: Please provide a working example that shows the problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Have you used the [scrollTo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo)

```
window.scrollTo(x-coord, y-coord)
```

Since you are using Jquery, there is one also available for JQuery [scrollTop()](https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/)

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    $( "div.demo" ).scrollTop( 100 );
});
```